# jquery to make textarea to convert contents into html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to convert anything that is entered in `<textarea></textarea>` to html so that it gets entered in database as an HTML format.

For example:

```
Hello Stackoverflow!

My name is Shubham. I am new here.
Please help me.
```

Should be inserted in database as:

```
Hello Stackoverflow!
<br><br>
My name is Shubham. I am new here.<br>
Please help me.
```

Can this be done with jQuery or Ajax? I googled for it a lot but the results I got was completely irrelevant for my issue. Please help.

Note: I do not want to use any WYSIWYG editor for some reasons. That is why I raised this question.

Happy Diwali !!

Comment: Hi, check functions `nl2br` and `str_replace` (and all others REGEX functions) (on php side)

Comment: You should use markdown https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it

An Example: http://dillinger.io/

Comment: will give a look.. :)

Comment: I'd rather suggest to do that conversion (nl2br) when displaying the content - not when saving.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, only ajax request left instead of putting in another textarea:

```js
$('#for_user').on('change input', function(){
  $('#for_database').val($(this).val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />'));  
});
$('#for_user').trigger('change');
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="for_user">
test
molimo
da iskušate
ovu metodu <a href="#">Link</a>
</textarea>
<br>
For database:<br>
<textarea id="for_database">
  
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question for those who visit this question in future. This will help them.

To insert the next lines from `<textarea></textarea>` with `<br>` to be entered in database I used `nl2br` function in post value. With nl2br all the next line statements automatically receives a `<br>`.

Example:

```
<?php 
$text = (!empty($_POST['content']))?nl2br($_POST['content']):null;

// then insert into or update database normally

$insert = "INSERT INTO table(field_name)VALUES(:value)";
$insert = $pdo->prepare($insert);
$insert->bindValue(':value', $text);
$insert->execute();

OR

$update = "UPDATE table SET field_name = :value";
$update = $pdo->prepare($update);
$update->bindValue(':value', $text);
$update->execute();
?>
```

This simply inserts or updates this:

```
Hello Stackoverflow!

My name is Shubham. I am new here.
Please help me.
```

As this:

```
Hello Stackoverflow!
<br><br>
My name is Shubham. I am new here.<br>
Please help me.
```